# trying to list customer details in one row in a new view, drawing information from two rows i find i am getting duplicate rows with nulls

Tags: sql, group-by, decode

trying to create a new view from 2 other tables, titled customer information.

currently statement reads

```
select c.customer_id, c.name, 
max(decode(cat.method_id, 'Phone', cat.value))phone,
max(decode(cat.method_id, 'Fax', cat.value))fax, 
max(decode(cat.method_id, 'Mobile', cat.value))mobile,
max(decode(cat.method_id, 'E-Mail', cat.value))email
from table_1 c, table_2 cat
where c.customer_id = cat.customer_id
group by c.customer_id, c.name
```

now the statement works fine and everything for one customer is on a single row however where the customer has 2 phone number records, i would like it to be concatinated in the first phone column, I tried to rank the values and use them in a subselect but cannot seem to get it all working together.

Comment: Try posting some sample data for the tables and then the sample output. You will certainly get an answer doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Undocumented oracle feature called WM_Concat

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/StringAggregationTechniques.php

11g function LISTAGG would also work

Comment: wm_concat just what i needed brilliant